# disable month in calendar thats not in list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, calendar

I am displaying a calendar on screen. The calendar highlights the dates stored in the list 'Diary Entry'. ATM the user can navigate through any month of any year, using the arrows at the top of the calendar. I only want the user to be able to navigate between the months that store dates so for e.g if the dates are btn 1/3/2013 & 4/7/2013 the user cant move the calendar to 5/8/2013, how is it possible to disable the arrow key when it hits a date?

```
<asp:Calendar ID="calendarToDisplayWorkSiteDates" VerticalAlign="top" HorizontalAlign="left" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="LoadRequestedDate_OnClick" OnDayRender="cal_DayRender"></asp:Calendar>

public void BindData()
        {
            DateTime Date = new DateTime(DiaryDate.Year, DiaryDate.Month, 1);
            DateTime startOfMonth = Date.AddMonths(-2);
            DateTime endOfMonth = startOfMonth.AddMonths(5).AddDays(-1);

            int siteId = this.siteId;

            ClarkeDBDataContext db = new ClarkeDBDataContext();
            List<Diary_Entry> DiaryEntry = new List<Diary_Entry>();

            DiaryEntry = (from DE in db.Diary_Entries
                          where DE.Site_Id == siteId
                          && DE.Date >= startOfMonth && DE.Date <= endOfMonth
                          orderby DE.Date ascending
                          select DE).ToList();

            if (DiaryEntry != null)
            {
                FirstDateLabel.Text = DiaryEntry.FirstOrDefault().Date.Date.ToShortDateString();
                SecondDateLabel.Text = DiaryEntry.LastOrDefault().Date.Date.ToShortDateString();

                foreach (DateTime d in DiaryEntry.Select(de => de.Date))
                {
                    calendarToDisplayWorkSiteDates.SelectedDates.Add(d);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                FirstDateLabel.Text = "None";
                SecondDateLabel.Text = "None";
            }


        }

        protected void cal_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Day.IsToday)
                e.Cell.BackColor = Color.Red;
            else if (e.Day.Date == this.DiaryDate)
                e.Cell.BackColor = Color.Green;
            else if (e.Day.IsSelected)
                e.Cell.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's possible (easily) to disable the arrow, the easiest would be to use the `DayRender` event to set the [`IsSelectable` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendarday.isselectable.aspx).

```
protected void cal_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.IsToday)
        e.Cell.BackColor = Color.Red;
    else if (e.Day.Date == this.DiaryDate)
        e.Cell.BackColor = Color.Green;
    else if (e.Day.IsSelected)
        e.Cell.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    // adjust accordingly
    if (e.Day.Date < MinDate || e.Day.Date > MaxDate)
    {
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        e.Cell.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
    }
}
```